# How can I translate "Risen from the dead" to latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

What would be the most appropriate translation for the sentence *"Risen from the dead"* to Latin?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you specify the context, and what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While Middle School Historian took the more classical approach, I would like to present you with the Catholic/Ecclesiastical approach. Hence, the Latin translation of the Apostles' Creed, or *Symbolum Apostolorum*:

> Credo in Deum Patrem omnipotentem, Creatorem caeli et terrae.
>
> Et in Iesum Christum, Filium eius unicum, Dominum nostrum, qui
>   conceptus est de Spiritu Sancto, natus ex Maria Virgine, passus sub
>   Pontio Pilato, crucifixus, mortuus, et sepultus, descendit ad inferos,
>   **tertia die resurrexit a mortuis**, ascendit ad caelos, sedet ad dexteram
>   Dei Patris omnipotentis, inde venturus est iudicare vivos et mortuos.
>
> Credo in Spiritum Sanctum, sanctam Ecclesiam catholicam, sanctorum
>   communionem, remissionem peccatorum, carnis resurrectionem, vitam
>   aeternam.
>
> Amen.

The important part is in bold. This translates as "on the third day he rose from the dead." So, by using the verb *resurgo*, one would get the phrase ***Resurrectus/a/um a mortuis***. Obviously, *resurrectus* would have to be declined with the proper agreeing noun. [Here](http://latin.cactus2000.de/showverb.en.php?verb=resurgere&gen=0&voc=2) is a link with all forms of the word if you need help with the agreement part.

---

The Nicene Creed (*Symbolum Nicaenum*) also corroborates this result:

> Credo in unum Deum, Patrem omnipotentem, factorem caeli et
>   terrae,visibilium omnium et invisibilium.
>
> Et in unum Dominum Iesum Christum, Filium Dei unigenitum, et ex Patre
>   natum ante omnia saecula.
>   Deum de Deo, Lumen de Lumine, Deum verum de Deo vero, genitum non
>   factum, consubstantialem Patri; per quem omnia facta sunt.
>   Qui propter nos homines et propter nostram salutem descendit de
>   caelis.
>   Et incarnatus est de Spiritu Sancto ex Maria Virgine, et homo factus
>   est.
>   Crucifixus etiam pro nobis sub Pontio Pilato, passus et sepultus est,
>   **et resurrexit tertia die**, secundum Scripturas, et ascendit in caelum,
>   sedet ad dexteram Patris.
>   Et iterum venturus est cum gloria, iudicare vivos et mortuos, cuius
>   regni non erit finis.
>
> Et in Spiritum Sanctum, Dominum et vivificantem, qui ex Patre Filioque
>   procedit.
>   Qui cum Patre et Filio simul adoratur et conglorificatur: qui locutus
>   est per prophetas.
>
> Et unam, sanctam, catholicam et apostolicam Ecclesiam.
>   Confiteor unum baptisma in remissionem peccatorum.
>   Et expecto resurrectionem mortuorum, et vitam venturi saeculi.
>
> Amen.

Answer (score 2):

A few options are:

> (re)surrectus a letho/morte
>
> ascensus a letho/morte

*Surrectus* means risen, and *resurrectus* means risen again.

*A* (*ab* before a vowel or *h*) means from or by.

*Letho* and *morte* are in the ablative case, meaning that someone or something has risen *from* them. They are both words for death. As far as I see, *lethum* is more poetic than *mors*.

If the subject is a thing and not a person, change *(re)surrectus* to *(re)surrectum*; if feminine specifically, *(re)surrecta*; if gender is unknown, -*us*.

Same gender-stuff with *ascensus*, meaning climbed up.

Note that if you find better words, decline them so. Wiktionary.org should provide these. The word you choose for death should be in the ablative singular.

Comment: If this is a Christian context, the stock phrase is definitely [*a mortuis*](https://www.biblegateway.com/quicksearch/?quicksearch=mortuis&qs_version=VULGATE): there's a subtle distinction between "the dead" and "death." I also don't think *ascendo* would be appropriate in this context.